# Tow Thomas biquad filter output amplitude is increasing as I increase frequency

Tags: filter, low-pass, active-filter

I was trying to simulate the Tow Thomas biquad filter and measure the output amplitudes of the second order low pass filter output.

The input is 100mv peak at 100Hz and I varied it gradually till 100kHz  but the amplitude of the output kept increasing.

Can anyone explain the increase of the output voltage amplitude? Shouldn't it be decreasing as I increase the input frequency?

This is a picture of the circuit I used to observe the output.

[image]

Comment: Did you try sweeping f  with a triangle and observe the envelope sync’d to scope ?

Comment: This is not the TT version with any variable 2nd order (biquadratic) filter response.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 are you sure ?? the 2nd amplifier output has to be 2nd order low pass filter

Comment: There are many different versions of the TT filter.  Each with different feed forward and feedback variations.  When f and Q are high your GBW must be the square of Q times f in your amp.  Try bigger C and sweep it.  Also here...   https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgwLN.jpg. And for faster tests, simulate on  http://www.Falstad.com/afilter

Comment: Try changing all R’s to 15k and see what happens after 10kHz

Comment: See here https://tinyurl.com/yr84sv

Comment: The 1st output increases with f then decreases BPF and last is a LPF all thanks to negative feedback.

Comment: lolls222, did you perform an ac analysis? For my opinion, this classical TT-biquad should work as desired with a quality factor of Q=10/15=0.666 and a pole frequency of wp=66krad/s (f=10.6 kHz). Question: WHERE did you measure? Note that the ouput of the first opamp is a bandpass function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing the BPF version where R2 controls Q of the output in the 1st stage.

You have 3 stages and 2 inputs on the 1st stage.

Stage 1: DC gain with LPF and negative feedback of LPF, 2) inverted LPF and 3) inverter which makes the output HPF + LPF by causing the 2nd LPF inverted to look like a HPF here only on Stage 1 output.

Stage 2, 3; These are just 2 cascaded LPF at 10kHz.

Here I [simulated](https://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%201165286.1862176745%0Aw%20272%20248%20248%20248%200%0Aw%20248%20208%20248%20248%200%0Aw%20352%20256%20352%20248%200%0Aw%20352%20256%20352%20208%200%0A170%20200%20248%20168%20248%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0Ac%20248%20208%20352%20208%200%201e-9%200%0Ar%20248%20176%20352%20176%200%20150000%0Aw%20248%20208%20248%20176%200%0Ar%20200%20248%20248%20248%200%2015000%0Aa%20272%20256%20352%20256%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20272%20264%20272%20304%200%0Aw%20400%20208%20400%20248%200%0Aw%20496%20256%20496%20248%200%0Aw%20496%20248%20496%20208%200%0Ac%20400%20208%20496%20208%200%201e-9%200%0Ar%20352%20248%20400%20248%200%2015000%0Aa%20424%20256%20496%20256%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20424%20264%20424%20304%200%0Ag%20552%20272%20552%20304%200%0Aa%20552%20264%20592%20264%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Aw%20552%20208%20552%20256%200%0Aw%20592%20264%20592%20208%200%0Aw%20496%20256%20496%20248%200%0Aw%20424%20248%20400%20248%200%0AO%20648%20136%20696%20136%200%0Ar%20496%20256%20552%20256%200%2015000%0Ar%20552%20208%20592%20208%200%2015000%0Aw%20592%20152%20592%20208%200%0Aw%20248%20152%20248%20176%200%0Aw%20352%20208%20352%20176%200%0Ar%20248%20152%20592%20152%200%2015000%0AS%20648%20136%20592%20136%200%202%20false%200%203%0Aw%20352%20176%20352%20120%200%0Aw%20496%20208%20496%20136%200%0Aw%20352%20120%20592%20120%200%0Aw%20496%20136%20592%20136%200%0Ax%20581%20103%20719%20106%200%2012%20Push%20(but%20try%20not%20to%20move)%0Ax%20265%20120%20315%20123%200%2024%20hello%0A) a more interesting BPF with a couple easy changes R1=15k, R2=150k .  since R2 controls inner loop gain but not the outer loop gain, it controls the Q of the BPF so Q=10 but only about 20dB gain -3dB = 17dB.

You may change any value and press the output selector switch.

Did U try the switch?

This was simulated with 1GHz GBW so gain of 20dB with a Q of 10 results in an open loop gain of only 10 at 10kHz resulting in a few dB less than 20dB. So you might have chosen GBW >= 10 MHz for < 0.5 dB gain error

Comment: thanks for explaining you were truly helpful!!!

Comment: Once you are happy no more answers are forthcoming, vote and chose your preferred answer.

Answer (score 2):

It might work with an ideal op-amp but you are asking too much from the op-amp.

Even the LM348 datasheet is from 1979, and the op-amp has gain-bandwidth only up to 1 MHz.

Capacitor impedance gets lower as frequency rises, and as as the op-amp non-idealities start to get larger when frequency rises, the signal will pass via capacitors and the non-ideal op-amp can't remove it.

Comment: It has unity gain of 100 at 10kHz and if using 20dB gain only 20 dB leftover  so it still works but about- 3dB gain error and phase shift causes +2% frequency error. So not that bad as it sounds, neglecting component tolerance errors.

Comment: -1/2. It works with a 1MHz GBW OA.